# Chrome Extensions: Getting the document.images.length from the current page, not the popup. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Olá, after a few hours looking for a solution I could not solve a "problem", so I'm here asking for help.
 My goal is to create a google extension that shows how many images there are on the current tab/page, to do this, I'm trying to use the javascript:

```
var x = document.images.length;
document.getElementById("idhere").innerHTML = x
```

with the html:

```
<p id="idhere"></p>
```

It works, but not the way I'd like it to, because it looks for the images in the extension's popup, not the tab (background?) page. Then it returns 0, since I have no images in my popup, but if I add an image it returns 1...

My question is: How to get the amount of images that are on the page "behind" the extension popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing @jess's answer:

First add the lines below in your **manifest.json**:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://anylinkhere.com/*"],
    "css": ["optionalstyle.css"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
}],
```

Then create the **contentscript.js** file in your extension's folder:

```
window.onload = function() {
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.images.length);
}
```

- *window.onload = function() {}*

will run when the page is fully loaded (required to load all the images)

- *chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.images.length);*

will send the message to your background.js, with the amount of images that are on the page.

And then, in your **background.js**, add:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse,) {
chrome.storage.sync.set({"x": (response)}, function() {
console.log('Set x as '+ (response));
});
});
```

- *chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener*...

receive the message sent by your contentscript.js

- *chrome.storage.sync.set({"x": (response)},*...

stores the response (the amount of images) value to x, then popup.js will be able to access.

- *console.log('Set x as '+ (response));*

log it (optional)

Now in your **popup.js**:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('x', function(data) {
document.getElementById("anyidhere").innerHTML = data.x;
});
```

- *chrome.storage.sync.get('x',*...

takes the X value from the storage

- *document.getElementById("anyidhere").innerHTML = data.x;*

Adds the value of X to the element with the specified id (from your popup.html), for example:

```
<body>
<p id="anyidhere"></p>
</body>
```

Well, that was all I learned by studying for two days, some information may not be correct or poorly explained, but it works.

This is *how you send information from the webpage to your popup*

Answer (score 0):

**Content scripts** are files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they are able to read details of the web pages the browser visits, make changes to them and pass information to their parent extension.

Here is the full documentation about manipulating DOM using [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Related SO posts:

- [Chrome extension, reading a content of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648849/chrome-extension-reading-a-content-of-html-element)
- [Chrome Extension: using document.querySelector in background script
  Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885877/chrome-extension-using-document-queryselector-in-background-script)

Comment: This should work, but I think it would be interesting if you update your answer by adding a specific solution to my question above so it could help people coming up here with the same problem/question...